# Why does snmp fail to use its own MIBs?

Tags: snmp, ubuntu-12.04

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS, and installed the snmpd and snmp packages.

If I type:

`snmpwalk -m ALL -v2c -c public localhost 1.3`

I get swathes of errors, of the form:

```
Cannot adopt OID in SQUID-MIB: cacheClients ::= { cacheProtoAggregateStats 15 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendLineIndex ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutLine ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
```

There a literally hundreds of these.

If snmp doesn't even like the distro-included MIBs, what chance to I have of getting my own used?  (I get the same form of error with my own MIB, on a different machine, which is why I set up a clean install to test the distro's sanity.)

Do other distros have this issue? Is there something obvious that I am overlooking here?

Comment: I was getting these on stdoud when running PHP from CLI (otherwise I wasn't) on Ubuntu server. They were beeing output by the PHP snmp module. The fix was `apt-get install snmp`. The mibs were present in the mibs folder already.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader`

The above command downloads various non-free MIBs which the free MIBs (included with distro) require to work.

There are still a handful of errors, after installing this non-free package, but the `snmpwalk` now works.

Comment: Thanks - your answer just saved me hours of logfile debugging. [+1]

Comment: FYI, still applies in 16.04LTS

Answer (score 4):

It seems you do not have snmp installed.
Just do

```
sudo apt-get install snmp
```

Comment: I was running a scanimage -T (Mint), doing a simple test, and got all these errors. Installing this cleared it out completely. While not the same cause of the SNMP errors, the underlining issue was the same. Not sure why you got a downvote, ++

Comment: The OP said "..installed the snmpd and snmp packages..."